# How to delete PDF files from the Documents folder via a MediaStore Uri

Tags: android, pdf, delete-file, mediastore

I’m creating PDF files and storing them in the default [Documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) folder, working only with MediaStore Uris, not SAF. Let’s put in context that I already have all the required/granted read+write permissions, and I’m the owner of the files being created and deleted.

For API levels **below Android Q**, deleting a PDF file (mime-type: **application/pdf**), fails only when such file is in the device’s **Documents** folder.

To fully delete it, the only way I’ve found would work, is first to delete it from the MediaStore, followed by a file deletion:

```
String filePath = helper.getPathFromMediaStore() // Get the path before removing from the MediaStore
contentResolver.delete(targetUri, null, null) // Remove from the MediaStore
new File(filePath).delete() // Remove from disk
```

This 2 steps delete operation already looks like an ugly hack as the File.delete() shouldn’t be necessary.

To makes things more complicated, in Android Q the second step File.delete() can't be used as the MediaStore.DATA column is deprecated.

If the PDF files are instead placed in the [Downloads](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) folder, then these can get deleted in all API levels, yet in API below Android Q the second step File.delete() is still required.

Conclusion, **PDF** files located in the **Documents** directory only get deleted from the MediaStore, but they remain on disk unless using the File.delete() hack, and which can't be used in Android Q.

So, is there any specific requirement to be able to delete **owned files** from the **Documents** folder, using only MediaStore Uris, for all API levels, and without File.delete operations?

Comment: "it still contains the file path, so is no problem to get it" -- it is redacted from `MediaStore` queries, at least in my testing. And you have no filesystem access to that path anyway on Android 10.

Comment: The File.delete() is just a hack which I would prefer to avoid in all Android versions. The main issue, is why isn't possible to fully delete PDF files in Documents directory, when I'm the creator and even  set as the owner in Android Q. By not deleting, I mean that yes they get deleted from the MediaStore using the ContentResolver.delete(Uri, ...), but the files remain on disk.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by being the "owner" of a file in the `Documents/` directory off the root of external storage on Android 10. Your app should have no ability to read or write to that directory on Android 10. `MediaStore` is supposed to have nothing to do with `Documents/` on Android 10 anyway (it's back to just media, plus `Downloads/` for some inexplicable reason).

Comment: So that is strange, because I'm able to create files in such directory with no problems at all. Need to mention that in Android 10 I'm using the RELATIVE_PATH field to set the destination, in this case Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS  + "/PDF". To get back the Uris, I query the ContentResolver using  MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)", which indeed returns all the owned PDF, so excluding files created by other apps.

Comment: "I'm able to create files in such directory with no problems at all" -- you are not creating them yourself, using Java file I/O (e.g., `File`). You are using `MediaStore`. I'm very surprised that `RELATIVE_PATH` accepts Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/PDF" as a relative path, but the fact that you are are using `MediaStore` itself helps explain what is going on.

Comment: Could you not delete the actual document via a `DocumentsContract` with the `contentResolver` you have?

e.g.
`DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), targetUri);
`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#deleteDocument(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri)

Not tried this method yet.

Comment: Can't use DocumentsContract because the files get created through the MediaStore using the ContentResolver, The Uris aren't SAF, are MediaStore content Uris.

Comment: I think part of your problem is according to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped you should be using SAF not MediaStore for PDF's

Comment: Doing more testing it seems the documentation may not be complete or is currently misleading. If I try to save a PDF into for example in DCIM, an exception is thrown stating that such file can be saved only in [Download, Documents], and vice versa, if trying to save a Photo into Documents it throws that it can be saved only in [DCIM, Pictures], So indeed the MediaStore allows to save PDF files in Documents. The exception when trying to save a PDF to DCIM: “Primary directory DCIM not allowed for content://media/external/file; allowed directories are [Download, Documents]”

Comment: `"I'm able to create files in such directory with no problems at all"` @PerracoLabs @CommonsWare It took me some time to find out how but now using the MediaStore i can create files in Documents and Download directory in primary partition and on microSD card. Those directories do not have to exist yet. They are created. Also Subdirectories get created. All on Q. Tested on Emulator Pixel 3.

Comment: The content schemes of such files look like content://media/131a-2e11/file/32 and the files let them delete with context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(scheme), null, null); Or what do you use using MediaStore ? @PerracoLabs.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem but with images, video and music. I do not own these files. I try to delete them via getContentResolver().delete(). I get RecoverableSecurityException, handle it, system displays dialog for user to give me access to this file, after the result I retry deletion and it succeeds, image/video/music is NOT present in mediastore, but IS present pn file system if I check via SAF or via file managers. when I restart the phone files appear in MediaStore again. I use scoped storage

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem too, and found no solution :(

Answer (score 1):

I met the problem also. My current solution is

For Android Q (API 29): I set android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" additionaly.

Hence.
new File(filePath).delete() // Remove from disk, it can work on Android Q

For Android R (API 30 or above)
I just use contentResolver.delete(targetUri, null, null). The mediastore record and physical file can all be deleted.

Could reference the https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases
It is complicated to
target on Android 11, Android 10 or Android 9 lower

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Does this actually work? If you check the file in a file explorer, isn't it still there?